# Extending Angular Material2 MdTab component

Tags: angular, inheritance, angular-material2

I'm attempting to extend one of the Material components, MdTabGroup. Everything works fine with the out-of-the box MdTabGroup component - the material library is correctly imported into the module etc.

Here's the extended component:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'md-custom-tab-group',
    templateUrl: 'custom-tab-group.html',
    ....
})
export class MdCustomTabGroup extends MdTabGroup {
  constructor( private _r : Renderer) {
    super(_r);
  }
}
```

The new component is imported and declared in the app module, and is created thus:

```html
<md-custom-tab-group>
    <md-tab>one</md-tab>
    <md-tab>two</md-tab>
</md-custom-tab-group>
```

The template for the custom tab group (`custom-tab-group.html`) is identical to the one in material, e.g.

```html
<div class="mat-tab-body-wrapper" #tabBodyWrapper>
    <md-tab-body role="tabpanel"
                 *ngFor="let tab of _tabs; let i = index"
                 ...
                 [content]="tab.content"
                 ...>
    </md-tab-body>
</div>
```

When run, the `_tabs` ViewChildren collection is getting correctly populated - it consists of the `md-tab` declarations in the original markup, interpreted as a Material tab component. However, the `custom-tab-group.html` template is *not* valid. The template parser now doesn't know what 'md-tab-body' is.

Specifically -

> Can't bind to 'content' since it isn't a known property of 'md-tab-body'.

but I don't think it knows what md-tab-body is at all when it picks up the new template.

The question is - how can I correct this behavior and get the extended component working?

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this? sort of facing the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

Not a good answer but this issue that is being tracked seems to be the root of it.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9216

Once they include MatTabBody, MatTabHeader and MatTabLabelWrapper in the export list you should be able to extend it.

Comment: or add 3 lines to sources on own https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/9218/files